# ARCore – Unable to create AR Session

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, android-studio-3.0, arcore

I am trying to open my model but it returns an error:

```
// Unable to create AR Session.
```

It shows 3d model but when I click for ar mode it returns an error on api 28. I tried my app with api 29, it worked perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using an ARCore feature that is specific to API Level 29 only.